# Backup and restore user passwords

Tags: password-recovery, passwd

Is it possible to make a file copy to backup users password and then restore them by copying them back?

It seems that the file in question is `/etc/shadow` as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file

My intention is to temporary change a users password, `sudo passwd user`. The original password is unknown to me. I would then restore it to the original password by replacing the `/etc/shadow` file with the previous copy. I.e.

```
sudo cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow.backup
sudo passwd user
sudo cp /etc/shadow.backup /etc/shadow
sudo rm /etc/shadow.backup
```

Is this possible or will I ruin the account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as no other changes happen in `/etc/shadow` *or* `/etc/passwd`, this should work just fine. If a user is added, deleted or modified and then you restore an old version, there may be trouble. If you can guarantee that nobody will do any operations involving `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` it will be OK.

You can also edit `/etc/shadow`, copy the encrypted password somewhere safe, do your password change, and then when needed set the password back to what it was. That way you don't need to touch anything else.

```
# Obtain the old password and save it in a file
echo $(sudo grep $USER /etc/shadow | cut -f 2 -d ':') >/safe/encrypted-pass
# Here, change the password, do whatever you need, then..
sudo usermod -p $(cat /safe/encrypted-pass) $USER
```

Note that the `-p` option to `usermod` "is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes." So it's up to you to decide if this is a risk that concerns you.

I prefer using commands to do this kind of manipulation, but you can accomplish the same thing manually with a simple text editor.

Comment: Thanks. The usermod ps listing will only be visible while `ps` is running correct?

Comment: Correct, so your window of vulnerability is very small.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe, it's not just `ps`, obviously the data is available to `ps` and thus to any tool that have the same capability. You can see the command line just using `cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline`. So it's not really that difficult to get the info if you're a _good enough_ hacker. If you are the only one of that server at the time, though, it's 100% safe.